# Trying to delete Android Realm file, but getting exception

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to delete the Realm file to clear cache when a user logs out.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(activity);

realm.close();
RealmConfiguration config = realm.getConfiguration();

Realm.deleteRealm(config);
```

I get this exception:

```
11-05 23:56:00.902 27521-27521/com.my.app E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It's not allowed to delete the file associated with an open Realm. Remember to close() all the instances of the Realm before deleting its file.
11-05 23:56:00.902 27521-27521/com.my.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.realm.Realm.deleteRealm(Realm.java:1726)
```

I'm obviously closing something, but its saying more are open? How do I close all of the realms so I can blow everything away and start fresh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances):

> Realm implements Closeable in order to take care of native memory
>   deallocation and file descriptors so it is important to remember to
>   close your Realm instances when you are done with them.
>
> Realm instances are reference counted, which means that if you call
>   getInstance() twice in a thread, you will also have to call close()
>   twice as well.

Probably you are missing to call `close()` on every Realm instance you created.

Check your code to find where `getInstance()` hasn't be matched by a `close()`.